# my 'History' object has no attribute 'predict' on my keras model

Tags: python, keras

im using this model:

```
from keras import models
from keras import layers
from keras.applications import VGG19
from keras import optimizers
from keras.layers.core import Flatten, Dense, Dropout, Lambda

conv_base = VGG19(weights='imagenet',
 include_top=False,
 input_shape=(150, 150, 3))
conv_base.trainable = False
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
 optimizer=optimizers.Adam(lr=LEARNING_RATE),
 metrics=['acc'])

STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_batches.n//train_batches.batch_size
STEP_SIZE_VALID=valid_batches.n//valid_batches.batch_size
result=model.fit_generator(train_batches,
 steps_per_epoch =STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
 validation_data = valid_batches,
 validation_steps = STEP_SIZE_VALID,
 epochs= NUM_EPOCHS
 )
```

to predict pneumonia from chest x-rays, then i want to create a heatmap about what does activate the last layer, i found this on the francois chollet book of deep learning w/ python

```
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.applications.vgg16 import preprocess_input, decode_predictions
import numpy as np
img_path = '/home/workstation/Desktop/covid/1.jpeg'
img = image.load_img(img_path, target_size=(150, 150))
x = image.img_to_array(img)
x = np.expand_dims(x, axis=0)
x = preprocess_input(x)

preds = result.predict(x)
print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds)[0])
```

but im getting this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-19-8607e0dccecf> in <module>
----> 1 preds = result.predict(x)
      2 print('Predicted:', decode_predictions(preds)[0])

AttributeError: 'History' object has no attribute 'predict'
```

if there any advice or help in order to solve this i will be very grateful w/ you people

Comment: You should predict with the model (model.predict), not with the return value of fit

Comment: you are right, jeje i fix it, but now i have another error in the decode_prediction, just asking do i should make a new question? or edit this one?

Comment: You can always edit your own question.